# Windows Forms App Basics: Deleting a row from a bound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control on a WinForms app that is bound from one of the tables in my database.  I would like this DataGridView to change whenever the user "Pulls" a row from the DataGridView to a separate DataGridView located next to it (that is initially blank and not bound to anything).

I'm sure you have seen something like this before, let me draw a diagram.  This would be an example of someone who has selected Row1 in the left DataGridView table, and then hit the Pull Button to pull it to the right DataGridView table:

```
Database:                       ToBeDeleted:
Row1               ______       Row1
Row2               |Pull|
Row3               |--->|                                                ______________
etc..              ------                                               |Remove Records|
```

Now, when the user "Pulls" over one of the records in the left table to the right table, I would like to left table to update itself to not have that Row in it anymore.  This way, the user cannot add two of the same row to the righthand table, and it instantly reflects the changes that they are about to make (since the righthand table represents records that are to be deleted from the lefthand table).

Comment: if it is bound, you delete/remove from the datasource

Comment: And there is no other way to accomplish this?  Because currently they can pull over 2 of the same row into the right hand table, hit the Remove Record button, and then a database exception is thrown because the same record was tried to be deleted twice from the database.

Comment: Perhaps one solution would be to simply check for any rows in the right hand table and check the rows that are to be pulled, and if there are any repeats then have a polite MessageBox popup show up which tells them they are adding the same row twice (as well as cancel the operation).  This isn't as user friendly, but it would suffice.

Comment: instead of a To Be Deleted paradigm, why not just delete it?  The other way is to have an hidden column to mark those to delete then filter out the ToBeDeleted ones in the DB DGV.  Then when you do get around to deleting, process only the DB DGV - the other one is eye candy

Comment: @Musicode Without knowing how your DAL is set up, it sounds almost as if you're being constrained by the IDE. Maybe this is the time to learn how to do it programmatically? As is, using data table: Just clone the table and use this as your right DGVs data source. Then, whenever a row is dragged, import the row (cloned table) and delete (source table).

Comment: Both good comments, two additional methods of dealing with this have been brought forward.  It's surprising that the DataGridView does not have a Delete method built in to it!

Comment: @Musicode A `DGV` ain't named a Datagrid **View** by accident. It's designed to display data, not to manipulate.

Comment: rather than worrying about the *control* deal with the data (see Mr Krigsja's DAL comment), and leave the control to the user to fiddle with and communicate to you what they want to do.

Comment: How would i go about changing/programming my own DAL?... I may be incorrect, but this seems like some advanced programming that I have no experience with yet, but I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong about your project and it's not difficult to do.
I'm using `Linq To Entities` for this sample so I have my database table mapped as objects.

[image]

1. Create 2 databound DGVs, bind them to 2 difference datasources (`BindingSource`) and choose `Object`. The object type is the same because you're binding them to the same database table (in my case the row object is called as its table, `Table3`)
2. Left DGV is bound to `Table3BindingSource`, right DGV to `Table3BindingSourceTBD`
3. Get data for the left DGV from database (a basic select from table)
4. The button `Pull` remove an object from left dgv and adds it to the other
5. The button `Delete` just loop thru the right rows, and handle the db delete action
6. Finally, query your db for updated data (left dgv) and clear the right dgv

sample:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetData()
End Sub

Sub GetData()
    Dim db = New StackOverflowEntities

    Table3BindingSource.DataSource = db.Table3.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id).ToList()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim x = CType(Table3BindingSource.Current, Table3)
        'remove from left dgv
        Table3BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        'add to right dgv
        Table3BindingSourceTBD.Add(x)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'delete rows in datagridview TBD

    Dim db = New StackOverflowEntities
    'loop rows
    For Each r In Table3BindingSourceTBD

        'cast right dgv row to underlying object
        Dim y = CType(r, Table3)

        'set object to be deleted
        Dim dr = (From x In db.Table3
                 Where x.Id = y.Id
                 Select x).Single()

        db.Table3.DeleteObject(dr)
    Next

    Try
        'commit changes to db
        db.SaveChanges()
        MsgBox("db updated")

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        'refresh all data in left dgv
        GetData()
        'simply clear right dgv
        Table3BindingSourceTBD.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I used basic `Linq To Entities` but anything would work (pure SQL, Linq2SQL...). If you need the project source just ask

good luck

Comment: So it's about editing the BindingSource and not the DGV itself.  I'm using DataSources and not BindingSources but perhaps this can be changed.  Right now I have it set up so that an error box pops up if they try to add a duplicate row, which is crude but it works, but I will see if I can change to use BindingSources in the context of this app.

Comment: Good solution, selected as answer.  Instead of connecting a database table directly to a DataGridView using LINQ, you connect it to a BindingSource first.  This gives a lot of extended functionality that a DGV may not have such as sorting, as well.